# Adding containers inside a div is not aligning the containers to the center and also how do I have the scroll effects while keeping their initial size

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/e2ohrLvx/2/
It seems to have some margin-right pushing the containers to the left but I want it to be kept in the center.
Also for the scroll, I need to put the height to 100 vh to have the scroll effect but it modifies the container height which I do not want.

Instead, I want it to have the containers like the following.

https://jsfiddle.net/e2ohrLvx/3/

the CSS code

```
.home {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container {
    background: black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
}

.listing {
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.listing::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}


/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */

.listing {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;
    /* Firefox */
}
```

The HTML code

```
    <html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Menu </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./fontawesome-free-5.13.0-web/css/all.css"> -->

</head>

<body>

    <div class="home">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>SOMETHING</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="listing">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- <h2>Experience</h3> -->

                <h3>TSOMETHING</h3>
                <div>
                    <div>SOMETHING</div>
                    <div> Something</div>
                </div>
                <div> SOMETHING <br> SOMETHING </div>

            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <!-- <h2>Experience</h3> -->

                <h3>TSOMETHING</h3>
                <div>
                    <div>SOMETHING</div>
                    <div> Something</div>
                </div>
                <div> SOMETHING <br> SOMETHING </div>

            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <!-- <h2>Experience</h3> -->

                <h3>TSOMETHING</h3>
                <div>
                    <div>SOMETHING</div>
                    <div> Something</div>
                </div>
                <div> SOMETHING <br> SOMETHING </div>

            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <!-- <h2>Experience</h3> -->

                <h3>TSOMETHING</h3>
                <div>
                    <div>SOMETHING</div>
                    <div> Something</div>
                </div>
                <div> SOMETHING <br> SOMETHING </div>

            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <!-- <h2>Experience</h3> -->

                <h3>TSOMETHING</h3>
                <div>
                    <div>SOMETHING</div>
                    <div> Something</div>
                </div>
                <div> SOMETHING <br> SOMETHING </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the margin of `.container` to `margin: 20px auto;` from `margin: 20px;`.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/oNBdJQR)

```css
.home {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.listing {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.listing::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}


/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */

.listing {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /* Firefox */
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>SOMETHING</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="listing">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- <h2>Experience</h3> -->

      <h3>TSOMETHING</h3>
      <div>
        <div>SOMETHING</div>
        <div> Something</div>
      </div>
      <div> SOMETHING <br> SOMETHING </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <!-- <h2>Experience</h3> -->

      <h3>TSOMETHING</h3>
      <div>
        <div>SOMETHING</div>
        <div> Something</div>
      </div>
      <div> SOMETHING <br> SOMETHING </div>

    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- <h2>Experience</h3> -->

      <h3>TSOMETHING</h3>
      <div>
        <div>SOMETHING</div>
        <div> Something</div>
      </div>
      <div> SOMETHING <br> SOMETHING </div>

    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- <h2>Experience</h3> -->

      <h3>TSOMETHING</h3>
      <div>
        <div>SOMETHING</div>
        <div> Something</div>
      </div>
      <div> SOMETHING <br> SOMETHING </div>

    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- <h2>Experience</h3> -->

      <h3>TSOMETHING</h3>
      <div>
        <div>SOMETHING</div>
        <div> Something</div>
      </div>
      <div> SOMETHING <br> SOMETHING </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the margin auto fixes the unalignment. 
I am also wondering how can I reduce the height of the boxes that are the boxes inside the container instead of it being 100vh as well? It is too large so I want it to be more like the header outside of the listing container

Comment: @Justastudent Give `.container` a height of `height: fit-content;`